# how to get top 1 Vendor name based on spends with application of slicers in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I want to get **top 1 vendor name** by **spend** which I am getting through

```
Top 1 Vendor = CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(PSL[VName]),TOPN(1,ALL(PSL),[Spend],DESC))

VName = vendor name
PSL = table name
Spend = another measure
```

This is working alright and fetching the top vendor name however if I put a **Country** and **Category** slicer, the Vendor name doesn't change accordingly. How do I make my measure dynamic to slicer selected values?

I did try one more thing but that is also not working -

```
CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(PSL[VName]),TOPN(1,ALLEXCEPT(PSL,PSL[Category]),[Spend],DESC))
```

Country will come from another table.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please provide more information, such as images or expected output and inputs, else it is hard to know what's your issue

Comment: it is just that my measure is not working if I select slicers. the vendor name is not changing according to the slicer selection. ( slicer of country and category).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it worked-

```
CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(PSL[VName]),TOPN(1,ALL(PSL[VName]),[Spend]),VALUES(PSL[VName]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Measure 2 = CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(PSL[VName]), FILTER(PSL, var _sp = PSL[Spend] return _sp = calculate(max([Spend]), ALLEXCEPT(PSL,PSL[CountryID]))))
```

Left -> sample table
Right -> output Table

[image]

Comment: 65 / 5000
Wyniki tłumaczenia
Your comment is of little help. I don't know what's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a measure with this formula:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE(PSL[VName]), TOPN(1, PSL, PSL[Spend], DESC))
```

[image: Output1]

[image: Output2]